# SQL Select Where date record created

Tags: sql, database

Is there a way in SQL to filter a query based on the date a specific record was added if I don't have a field that has the date it was created on.

Something like this:

```
Select * from Table where Table.recorddate = '2013-01-01'
```

Comment: `if I don't have a field that has the date it was created on`?  You'll need to create that field, it's not something system maintained for you that you can access without having created it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, system maintained was what i was going for. Oh well, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that what you are trying to achieve is not possible. If it's really necessary, just add the field. It'd be easier for you that way.

Answer (score 1):

Use UTC format:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE recorddate = '2014-01-01'
```

Note that UTC is YYYY-MM-DD. So Today's date would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE recorddate = '2014-05-19'
```

If your date field also includes a time stamp you can use a between:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE recorddate BETWEEN '2014-05-19 00:00:00' AND '2014-05-19 23:59:59'
```

Comment: The point the OP is making is that there ***isn't*** a `recorddate` field.

Comment: I believe that was added as an edit after I answered :) Hence the upvote someone gave me.